# c++builder bpl's and static members have more than one static instances

Tags: c++builder

IN C++Builder (2009 - Windows 7) I've made a component which includes a header file that has a class with a static member variable - there seems to be two instances of the static member variable as described below.

I've a static member variable in a class e.g.

```
class theclass {
  static theclass *ref;
  ...
}
```

This is in theclass.h.

in theclass.cpp I have the initialiser

```
theclass *theclass::ref = NULL
```

Now I have a component that includes the header in a bpl and links to the .cpp file, and I also include this file in my main app and link there, in the main app theclass::ref is initialised to a new instance of theclass like

```
theclass *instance = new theclass().
```

I have an application with a few of the new components in it. When instance is called from the application code then all is good, when instance is called from the code in the bpl then it's a NULL and it crashes? It seems like there are two static variables one scoped in the bpl and one in main - any suggestions would be appreciated?

(probably should mention this is my first c++builder component - written many delphi components)

[Update]
If I turn off 'Build with run time packages' then it works - so seems to have something to do with dynamic linking?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try `#pragma package(smart_init,weak)` in the cpp file, so only this file gets staticly linked.